# Difference between tensorflow flattening methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I came across 2 different methods of flattening the convolution pool but I do not understand why both method works. The first method, is quite straight forward to me, given from the tensorflow [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) uses:

```
pool2 = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
```

However, I came across another code using the following:

Here, `conv2` is taken from the convolution layer.

```
pool2 = tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_max(conv2, 1), squeeze_dims=[1])
```

both are then passed to

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2, units=MAX_LABEL, activation=None)
```

which `logits` is finally used to calculate the `entropy`

```
entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tf.one_hot(y_, MAX_LABEL), logits=logits))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shapes of `conv2` tensors are the same in both examples?
I think the second one has reshaped the tensor in advanced.

The shape of `conv2` in tensorflow example is `(batch, y, x, filters)`, while the second one would be  `(batch, y*x, 1, filters)` so the following code can work normally.

And these two approaches have the same output, if the size of `conv2` is the same as `pool_size` (2x2 in this case), which will only output one value per filter and this is 
totally the same idea as `reduce_max`.

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
'The same input, but different shape' 
random_tensor = np.random.random([16,2,2,64])
method1_input=tf.constant(random_tensor)             # shape = (16,2,2,64)
method2_input=tf.reshape(method1_input,[16,4,1,64])  # shape = (16,4,1,64)
'method 1 : maxpool'
maxpool      = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=method1_input, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
maxpool_flat = tf.reshape(maxpool, [-1,64])

'method 2 : reduce_max and squeeze'
red_max = tf.reduce_max(method2_input, 1)   # shape = (16,1,64)
pool2   = tf.squeeze(red_max, squeeze_dims=[1])  # shape = (16,64)  ,literally squeeze dim [1]

with tf.Session() as sess :
    method1_result=(sess.run(maxpool_flat) )
    method2_result=(sess.run(pool2) )
    Is_true = sess.run(tf.equal(method1_result,method2_result)  )
    print(Is_true)
    # output
    #[[ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
    # [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
    # [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
    # ...
    # [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
    # [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
    # [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]]
```